# Convert an RDD to a DataFrame in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, type-conversion, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have `textRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]`

I would like to convert it to a DataFrame. The columns correspond to the title and content of each page(row).

Answer (score 1):

Use `toDF()`, provide the column names if you have them.

```
val textDF = textRDD.toDF("title": String, "content": String)
textDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [title: string, content: string]
```

or

```
val textDF = textRDD.toDF()
textDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: string]
```

The shell auto-imports (I am using version 1.5), but you may need `import sqlContext.implicits._` in an application.

Comment: Scala version of `toDF` supports only column names, not schema. If you want to provide schema you have to use `SQLContext. createDataFrame`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to columns. Schema means something different.

Comment: I would actually drop type annotations as well: `toDF("title", "content")`. There is really nothing to gain but for someone not familiar with Scala it may suggest that it is actually connected to the column types.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this like the following:

Create a case class like this:

```
case class DataFrameRecord(property1: String, property2: String)
```

Then you can use map to convert into the new structure using the case class:

```
rdd.map(p => DataFrameRecord(prop1, prop2)).toDF()
```