# Dataframe creation in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

```
wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('cat',), ('elephant',), ('rat',), ('rat',), ('cat', )], ['word'])
```

This is a way of creating dataframe from a list of tuples in python. How can I do this in scala ? I'm new to Scala and I'm facing problem in figuring it out.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an RDD to a DataFrame in Spark using Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023330/convert-an-rdd-to-a-dataframe-in-spark-using-scala)

Answer (score 6):

One simple way,

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List( (1,"a"), (2,"b") )).toDF("key","value")
```

and so `df.show`

```
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
+---+-----+
```

Refer to the worked example in [Programmatically Specifying the Schema](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) for constructing a `DataFrame` with `createDataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataframe , you need to create SQLContext .

```
val sc: SparkContext // An existing SparkContext.
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame , after importing it you can use .toDF method
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

now you can create dataframes

```
val df1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 5).map(i => (i, i * 2)).toDF("single", "double")
```

learn more about creating dataframes [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes)